# System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, web-config

when I debug my project, there are 5 messages (example: Could not find schema information for the element 'entityFramework'. Web.config) and the application doesn't work (error: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.).

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
   <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS ; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="HistoryContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;data source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And the object 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection' doesn't exist.
What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and I've got rid of it. My web config however referred to a version of 4.4 (not 4.3.1 as you have) which as far as I know doesn't exist. This arose after I grabbed a starter package for the WebAPI with MVC4 from somewhere or other.

V4.3.1 and now V5.0 pre-release do exist as of Aug 2012

I got the nuget package for 4.3.1 using the solution level "library package manager". This is an important step as I could choose which projects to apply it to.

During this process, my web config was changed (to ref 4.3.1) and the problem went away.

What bugs me is that reference to "System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection" cos I cant find where it exists but at least VS isn't complaining any more.